# SQL Query Help after 13th row Dynamic and in 12th row static values with a formula help pls.. posting DDL and DML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

---step 1
----===Create a SQL Table with below SQL Query

```
USE [abc]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IC_Raw_In](
        [I_Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [I_O_P] [money] NULL,
        [I_O_H] [money] NULL,
        [I_O_L] [money] NULL,
        [I_C_O] [money] NULL,
        [I_Serial] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

---step 2
--===Insert the Data into IC_Raw_In Table as a bulk... Since i get the data every time bulk i must use here a bulk data

```
BULK
INSERT dbo.IC_Raw_In
FROM 'C:\ABC\InputData.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''
)
GO
```

---step 3
---====Create a SQL View for AMPS12_C

```
USE [abc]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AMPS12_C] AS


WITH RankedPrices
AS
(SELECT    i_serial , I_C_O, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i_serial) AS rn
FROM         IC_Raw_In)
    SELECT    a.i_serial, AVG(b.I_C_O) AS AMPS12_C
     FROM         RankedPrices AS a LEFT  JOIN
                            RankedPrices AS b ON b.rn BETWEEN a.rn-11 AND a.rn 
GROUP BY a.i_serial
GO
```

---step 4
---=== Create a view as v_AMP_C for easy output view

```
create view v_AMP_C as
SELECT   dbo.IC_Raw_In.I_Date, dbo.IC_Raw_In.I_O_P, dbo.IC_Raw_In.I_O_H, dbo.IC_Raw_In.I_O_L, dbo.IC_Raw_In.I_C_O, dbo.AMPS12_C.AMPS12_C, 
           dbo.IC_Raw_In.I_Serial
FROM     dbo.IC_Raw_In INNER JOIN
           dbo.AMPS12_C ON dbo.IC_Raw_In.I_Serial = dbo.AMPS12_C.i_serial
```

**---step 5 pending (I am looking for help here)**

Now I want write a SQL Query to get results in new Column called C12WR for the below quetion.

I want to exclude(Use NULL) the first 11 rows in C12WR Column, and in 12th row of C12WR Column "use a static value which is in “AMPS12_C” . This value will change every time i import the data to my table so the will change dynamically every time. And in the AMPS12_C Column it should calculate the below formula after 13th row to end of the table.

After 13th Row in C12WR Column = (the value of above row (that is currunt row number -1) from C12WR *11 + Current row value from I_C_O Column) /12

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331279/sql-query-help-after-13th-row-dynamic-and-in-12th-row-static-values-with-a-formul and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344954/sql-query-help-after-13th-row-dynamic-and-in-12th-row-static-values-with-a-formul

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic SQL by storing a SQL query in a string (varchar or nvarchar) and then running exec() on it.

`declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
declare @id as int = 1`

set @sql = 'select * from table where id =' + id

exec(@sql)

You would just have to dynamically determine the column names.